# Applying the theme outside the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to learn jquery mobile and have been playing around with it for the past few days and things are going alright, but I'm not so sure if I'm taking the proper approach.

I tried making a site with a similar UI as the facebook app. On the top right and left corners of the page's header are buttons that causes the page to slide out like a drawer.

The top left button will slide the page out to the right to reveal a menu, while the top right button will slide out to the left to reveal a form to fill out.

What I did was create divs outside the page and used javascript to slide out the active page, to reveal the menu or form depending on which button is pressed:

```
<body>

  <div id="my-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page1.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- end of my-menu -->

  <div id="my-form">
    <form method="post" action="form-action.php">
      <!-- form elements -->
    </form>
  </div> <!-- end of my-form -->

  <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of home -->

</body>
```

I used my own CSS to style the menu, but I also noticed my theme wasn't applied to "my-form", but everything in the page "home" had all elements properly styled.

I can't put the form inside the page "home" because I will not be able to do sliding drawer effect that I've done with the menu.

Am I suppose to have my own styling applied to the form outside the page or is there a way to apply the jquery mobile theme to elements outside the page?

Would this be the best approach to implement this kind of user interface or is there a better way using what's available in jquery mobile?

Since this will be my UI for the application does that mean I will just copy the same code to all the pages? Or is there a better way to do this?

I'd like to use the best practice for this use case so please offer any advice!
Thanks in advance for the help!

BTW I did the slide menu based on this blog post:
http://blog.aldomatic.com/facebook-style-slide-out-menu-in-jquery-mobile/

Comment: You have an error in page div tag. Change id="home to id="home" And only page content will have jQM styles applied. Your form is outside.

Comment: oops! Thanks for catching that typo. Yeah I realized the styles can't be applied but then is there a better way of doing this, or will I have to make a new style just for that form outside? I wanted to use the same style and use the flip switches and other form elements that are part of jQM.

Comment: You will need to create your own style, if you take a look at that blog post, its owners is using his own css to style left menu. Then again, I dont know if this is going to work but you can add data-role="page" to form div container, maybe that will help. But I dont think it is possible to have 2 active pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

As I told you in comments, jQM style can not be applied outside of page container but that should not prevent you from using its css.

If you are using firefox, use firebug plugin and take a look at every jQM page element, copy its structure and css. Use it to create styling outside page container.

One more thing, new elements are going to be styled but they will not have functionality, you will need to redo it by yourself.

**Solution2:**

Have your content inside a data-role="page" div at page-load, let jQuery Mobile style the page, and then move your content div out of the data-role="page" div to be a child of the body tag.

Comment: Yeah it was alright that the menu had no jQM functionality because it was all links but was hoping there was some way to have jQM form functionality and style even if it's elements outside of the data-role="page". It just doesn't feel right to redo it again just because it's outside the page. I'll try to explore other solutions and if ever I find something will update this. Thanks for the input Gajotres!